NavigationManager.NavigateTo() is getting Error like.A task was cannceled in Blazor
I am not sure what is the issue with Navigation. User can't face any issue in UI.Error coming like that
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager
EventId: 4
SpanId: b82db6f5b6c25d6b
TraceId: e73d3adb1f0792f46387c11162dbbed8
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 400014f1-0004-f100-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /_blazor
TransportConnectionId: MbL6ztAju3B5Ce3jnJIi3w
Navigation failed when changing the location to /petform/52844/0
Exception:
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, String identifier, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<g__PerformNavigationAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
I want to navigate the page after the Pet submit in the database

Code? You have shared an error but none of the code that causes it. How to ask
